# Moving OS to ssd drive

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I was thinking of getting a ssd drive but i worried about moving windows to it.

The computer i'm thinking of doing it on is a hp computer and i got no disks with it, windows was pre installed, it has a back up partion on it but how would i move it from my old hdd to the ssd ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot say that my current drive is 1tb the size i was planing to get a 240gb ssd and and there is 180gig of data i wanted to mirror onto it would that change any of the replys i got ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are talking about Windows 7, if your SSD is larger than the hard disk you have currently, you can do the following:

1. Connect both drives and load from the old disk,
2. Create a software RAID 1:

   1. Start `diskmgmt.msc`
   2. Right-click on the current partition and click on Add Mirror.
   3. Select the SSD in the list of disks.
3. Shut down the computer.
4. Unplug the old drive, but keep the SSD.
5. Load from SSD by selecting `[...] secondary plex` in the boot menu.
6. Start `diskmgmt.msc` and remove the (broken) mirror.

Comment: Huh. Never thought to use RAID to clone a drive before... are you sure that'll work? Clever idea!

Comment: It worked for me. I do it every time (for example I did it with Windows 7 before installing Windows 8 Consumer Preview). It has, on the other hand, some weak points: you must have a larger (or same space) drive (if I remember well, you can't shrink the OS partition), and you must remember that you still need to make backups.

Comment: You actually can shrink the OS partition from `diskmgmt.msc`. Just right-click on the partition and choose "Shrink Volume." So I suppose you could shrink it before setting up the RAID.

Answer (score 0):

Its a tough one, HP recovery discs do not support Advanced Format drives on most models, either conventional or SSD.

You can make a set of HP [recovery DVDs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01895783#WhenCreate) or a [USB thumbdrive](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01890478&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en) (Notebooks)

[Desktop USB or DVD](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01867124&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en#N43)

[There is 3rd party software](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/migrate-OS-to-SSD/) that may be able to help with migrating your current partition structure to a SSD, I have never used it to migrate to SSD, so I cannot vouch for it, but use other Paragon drive software without issue.

Post your exact HP model and I can do some more research for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SSD units you are looking at.  Some will come with imaging software to move the install from the existing drive to the new SSD. For example, Intel was shipping [Acronis Data Migration Tool](http://www.acronis.com/company/inpress/2010/10/29-07-52.html)

Answer (score -3):

It's not recommendable move a windows installation. You could do it, but com objects and some registry entries that uses the uid hardware of the hard drive can be corrupt and surely you could get lots of errors or simply it will no boot.

Comment: -1 That's weird because I've done cloning one Windows installation/hdd to another without a problem.